# VS Code не запускает python файл

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, компилятор

```
PS D:\Desktop\Разработка\Проект>  & 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' 'c:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '51666' '--' 'd:\Desktop\азработка\роект\main.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 444, in main        
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 285, in run_file    
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 267, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 237, in _get_code_from_file
    with io.open_code(decoded_path) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'd:\\Desktop\\азработка\\роект\\main.py'
PS D:\Desktop\Разработка\Проект>
```

Вот что выдает терминал, когда запускаю свой код.Как бы я понимаю, что компилятор сообщает о том, что данного расположения у файла не существует, но блин вот само расположение.

Почему в idle все нормально работает, а в vs code принимает данный путь-'d:\Desktop\азработка\роект\main.py'
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно поможет такой финт.
Для вашего проекта в файле tasks.json:

```
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Py_Run",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "python \"${file}\"",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

VScode предлагает создать его по `ctrl+sift+b`.
Или в ручную в `PROJECT_NAME/.vscode/tasks.json`

Answer (score 0):

Надо чтобы путь был не `D:\Desktop\Разработка\Проект>`, а `D:\Desktop\разработка\проект>`, то есть с маленькой буквы.

У меня сработало.